# Is it possible to nest SQL tables?

Tags: sql

I am wondering if it is possible to nest SQL tables? Or it the best practise to give the id to for example a person in the first table that is the key to the second table?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: you typically do this with a proper foreign key relationship between two tables. While some DBMS do support this (e.g. Oracle and to some extent Postgres) it's usually not such a goo idea.

Answer (score 1):

If by "nesting" you're referring to the "subtable view" that you get in Access - that's a UI representation of a foreign-key relationship, which is exactly what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

You do not nest tables. A notation style such as [crow foot notation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/878359/Data-modelling-using-ERD-with-Crow-Foot-Notation) allows you to architect the relationships. One Box may have many Burrito's, One Burrito may have many Beans. A ID with a Primary and Foriegn Key or Composite Key would be the standard ways of linking the tables.
**Edit**
Box Primary Key **ID** is linked to Burrito Foreign Key **BoxID** as an SQL Constraint.

**More Information**

- www.techopedia.com/definition/5547/primary-key
- www.techopedia.com/definition/6572/composite-key
- www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: Thanks, so you use foreign keys to link between tables?

Comment: Yes, Primary Key will be referenced by the Foreign Key.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle it is possible to have a table as a type and then have a column in another table of that type or simply nested tables.

In SQL Server I don't remember but I think it might be possible as you can create user type of Table type.

Check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx

Comment: You can do something similar in Postgres with an array of a custom type.

Comment: Sorry no knowledge of Postgres but I would like to thank you for giving me that knowledge :) In future I can tell other users that it is possible in Postgres as well.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in SQL Server at all. The user defined (table) types cannot be used to define columns of a (regular) table.

Comment: Agreed not possible in SQL Server. It gives the message: Msg 350, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The column "testcolumn" does not have a valid data type. A column cannot be of a user-defined table type.